# How to configure connection between Spring boot application and MS SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to change my database from MySQL to MS SQL Server in order to use live update in Microsoft Power Bi, however, I am having some issues when trying to create the configuration for the connection in the `application.properties` file. When I run the program I see a lot of errors too many to print but I think it's fair to assume that the configuration causes them because it works fine if I were to migrate back to a MySQL Database.

This is the configuration code:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=brs
spring.datasource.username=jay
spring.datasource.password=M@nUnit3dBaCk0nT0p
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2019Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

These are the parameters used to connect to the server `A003-E5490` is the PCs name
[image: Connection to the Server]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;encrypt=true;user=jay;password=M@nUnit3dBaCk0nT0p;`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch no still getting errors, for example this is just one of them `org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table user (user_id bigint identity not null, email varchar(255), first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), mobile_number varchar(255), password varchar(255), primary key (user_id))" via JDBC Statement`

Comment: Are you using [JDBC Driver 10.2 for SQL Server](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/jdbc-driver-10-2-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3100754) or later? It defaults to `encrypt=true;` but requires `trustServerCertificate=true;` when connecting to SQL Servers with self-signed certificates (which is pretty much everything outside of Azure).

Comment: Please add the full error here, because it is impossible to say what is your problem. And the good idea is to not share your password on the internet 

Comment: The server name is `A003-E5490` do you need to put it in the url instead of `localhost`: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:A003-E5490;databaseName=brs`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'm not sure, I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18, and the JDBC driver dependency from the Spring Initializer.

Comment: could be also a port issue "jdbc:sqlserver://<server>:<port> ....", consult with your DBA

Comment: you probably need to set the database in jdbc url as well. You can also see which port number it uses by running following query: select distinct local_net_address, local_tcp_port from sys.dm_exec_connections where local_net_address is not null

Comment: or exec xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on'